# HH606 hardhat compile error/ version issue

Tags: solidity, erc-20, hardhat

I have tried everything I know to do (which is limited, ill admit) and I cannot seem to resolve this error.

Error HH606: The project cannot be compiled, see reasons below.

The Solidity version pragma statement in these files doesn't match any of the configured compilers in your config. Change the pragma or configure additional compiler versions in your hardhat config.

- @openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol (^0.8.0)
- @openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/extensions/IERC20Metadata.sol (^0.8.0)
- @openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/IERC20.sol (^0.8.0)
- @openzeppelin/contracts/utils/Context.sol (^0.8.0)
- @openzeppelin/contracts/access/Ownable.sol (^0.8.0)

These files import other files that use a different and incompatible version of Solidity:

- contracts/AccessControl.sol (^0.5.0) imports @openzeppelin/contracts/access/Ownable.sol (^0.8.0)
- contracts/BCToken.sol (^0.5.0) imports @openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol (^0.8.0)

To learn more, run the command again with --verbose

Read about compiler configuration at https://hardhat.org/config

For more info go to https://hardhat.org/HH606 or run Hardhat with --show-stack-traces
PS C:\Users\smart\WEB3-GAME\Contracts> npx hardhat compile
Error HH411: The library @openze
import, imported from contracts/BCToken.sol, is not installed. Try installing it using npm.

For more info go to https://hardhat.org/HH411 or run Hardhat with --show-stack-traces
PS C:\Users\smart\WEB3-GAME\Contracts> npx hardhat compile
Error HH404: File @openzeppelin/contracts/access/ERC20/ERC20.sol, imported from contracts/BCToken.sol, not found.

For more info go to https://hardhat.org/HH404 or run Hardhat with --show-stack-traces
PS C:\Users\smart\WEB3-GAME\Contracts> npx hardhat compile
Error HH606: The project cannot be compiled, see reasons below.

The Solidity version pragma statement in these files doesn't match any of the configured compilers in your config. Change the pragma or configure additional compiler versions in your hardhat config.

- contracts/AccessControl.sol (0.8.0)
- contracts/BCToken.sol (0.8.0)
- @openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol (^0.8.0)
- @openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/extensions/IERC20Metadata.sol (^0.8.0)
- @openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/IERC20.sol (^0.8.0)
- @openzeppelin/contracts/utils/Context.sol (^0.8.0)
- @openzeppelin/contracts/access/Ownable.sol (^0.8.0)

To learn more, run the command again with --verbose

Read about compiler configuration at https://hardhat.org/config

For more info go to https://hardhat.org/HH606 or run Hardhat with --show-stack-traces
PS C:\Users\smart\WEB3-GAME\Contracts> npx hardhat compile
Error HH606: The project cannot be compiled, see reasons below.

The Solidity version pragma statement in these files doesn't match any of the configured compilers in your config. Change the pragma or configure additional compiler versions in your hardhat config.

- contracts/AccessControl.sol (^0.8.0)
- contracts/BCToken.sol (^0.8.0)
- @openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol (^0.8.0)
- @openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/extensions/IERC20Metadata.sol (^0.8.0)
- @openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/IERC20.sol (^0.8.0)
- @openzeppelin/contracts/utils/Context.sol (^0.8.0)
- @openzeppelin/contracts/access/Ownable.sol (^0.8.0)

To learn more, run the command again with --verbose

Read about compiler configuration at https://hardhat.org/config

For more info go to https://hardhat.org/HH606 or run Hardhat with --show-stack-traces
PS C:\Users\smart\WEB3-GAME\Contracts> npx hardhat compile
Error HH606: The project cannot be compiled, see reasons below.

The Solidity version pragma statement in these files doesn't match any of the configured compilers in your config. Change the pragma or configure additional compiler versions in your hardhat config.

- contracts/AccessControl.sol (^0.8.0)
- contracts/BCToken.sol (^0.8.0)
- @openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol (^0.8.0)
- @openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/extensions/IERC20Metadata.sol (^0.8.0)
- @openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/IERC20.sol (^0.8.0)
- @openzeppelin/contracts/utils/Context.sol (^0.8.0)
- @openzeppelin/contracts/access/Ownable.sol (^0.8.0)

AccessControl.Sol

//SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/access/Ownable.sol";

contract AccessControl is Ownable {

mapping(address => bool) public admins;

function setAdmin(address user, bool enable) external onlyOwner {
admins[user] = enable;
}

modifier onlyAdmin() {
require(
msg.sender == owner() || admins[msg.sender] == true,
"AccessControl: Caller doesn't have admin access"
);
_;
}
}

BCToken.sol

//SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol";
import "./AccessControl.sol";

contract BCToken is ERC20, AccessControl {

```
 constructor(uint256 amount) ERC20("BCToken", "BCT") public {}

function mint(address user, uint amount) 
    external 
    onlyAdmin 
    returns(bool)
{
    _mint(user, amount);
    return true;
```

hardhat.config.js

require("@nomicfoundation/hardhat-toolbox");

require("dotenv").config();

/** @type import('hardhat/config').HardhatUserConfig */
module.exports = {
solidity: {
compilers: [
{
version: "0.5.7",
},
{
version: "0.6.7",
settings: {},
},
],
},
networks: {
sepolia: {
url: "https://sepolia.infura.io/v3/",
accounts: [process.env.KEY],
}
}
}

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The contracts you're trying to compile (namely, `AccessControl.sol` and `BCToken.so`l) are written for Solidity version "^0.8.0", but those are not the version you specify in `hardhat.config.js`.

Lets update `hardhat.config.js` for Solidity version 0.8.0 and it should work.

```
require("@nomicfoundation/hardhat-toolbox");
require("dotenv").config();

/** @type import('hardhat/config').HardhatUserConfig */
module.exports = {
    solidity: {
        compilers: [
            { version: "0.5.7" },
            { version: "0.6.7", settings: {} },
            { version: "0.8.0", settings: {} }, // Add this line.
        ],
    },
    networks: {
        sepolia: {
            url: "https://sepolia.infura.io/v3/",
            accounts: [process.env.KEY],
        },
    },
};
```

Comment: Man, I have been going nuts for 3 days trying to get these to compile.  There simply isn't a whole lot of info out there on certain Solidity errors.  BIG THANKS!!!

Comment: You welcome :) dont forget to validate the answer if it fixed your problem